# Conceptual data modeling: Is RDF the right tool? Other solutions?

Tags: data-modeling, rdf, semantics, conceptual

I'm planning a system that combines various data sources and lets users do simple queries on these.  A part of the system needs to act as an abstraction layer that knows all connected data sources: the user shouldn't [need to] know about the underlying data "providers". A data provider could be anything: a relational DBMS, a bug tracking system, ..., a weather station.  They are hooked up to the query system through a common API that defines how to "offer" data.  The type of queries a certain data provider understands is given by its "offer" (e.g. *I know these entities, I can give you aggregates of type X for relationship Y, ...*).

My concern right now is the unification of the data: the various data providers need to agree on a common vocabulary (e.g. the name of the entity "customer" could vary across different systems).  Thus, defining a high level representation of the entities and their relationships is required.

So far I have the following requirements:
I need to be able to define objects and their properties/attributes. Further, arbitrary relations between these objects need to be represented:  a verb that defines the nature of the relation (e.g. "knows"), the multiplicity (e.g. 1:n) and the direction/navigability of the relation.

**It occurs to me that RDF is a viable option, but is it "the right tool" for this job?**

**What other solutions/frameworks do exist for semantic data modeling that have a machine readable representation and why are they better suited for this task?**

I'm grateful for every opinion and pointer to helpful resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need cardinality restrictions on relations (for example "a Person knows 1:n Languages"), then RDF is not enough (see http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-rdf-primer-20040210/#richerschemas). You will need ontology languages (at least OWL-DL for cardinalities greater than 1: http://www.w3.org/TR/owl-guide/#owl_cardinality)

Answer (score 2):

I'd also consider an XML database and xquery, and perhaps topic maps (which is quite similar to RDF, but less widely known).

There are also a broad range of less standardised tools to consider, things like couchdb (which uses json).

There's rarely a 'right tool', but RDF is a very strong contender given your requirement.