# DCMI, RDF - Cardinalities and Occurences

Tags: metadata, rdf, cardinality

**Is it common to define cardinalities for properties (relationships) within DCMI or RDF schemas?**

The existing content regarding this topic is quite limited, but there are resources showing the use of cardinalities (but not in official documents from DCMI or W3).

E.g. see occurence here:

[image]

Comment: What kind of answer do you expect on this question? Discussion? Guesses?

Comment: A recommendation would be good!

Comment: I think it is hard to give a good answer to this question. You ask "Is it common...", then imply in your explanation that it is not very common. I think you can only give subjective answers to that. Whether specifying cardinalities is a good thing depends on the context. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/2373438/1445526 and note that DCMI application profiles and RDF Schema are different things.